# Proximity in a Table View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm programming an application that lists a number of locations. I have the coordinates stored in a .plist, which I am using as a data source. I have trouble figuring out how to conceptually approach problems, so some help would help :)

I would like to Have the name of the location sit on the left while on the right of the table view, you can see how far away from the location you are (in miles / kilometers). Is there a convenient way to push this information to the table and sort the list?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and it isn't apparent what work you have done to try to solve it. All of the information that you need to accomplish this is readily available on the web. If you are looking for someone to code the whole thing for you, then you are missing the point of StackOverflow. If you are stuck on a specific part of this problem, then post the relevant code and ask specific questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to port your plist data into a datasource NSArray for the UITable. You can use sorting functions of NSArray to sort your data at anytime and do refresh on the table. B/c you want non-standard data in the table cell you will have to design your own custom UITableCellView. You can find lot of examples on Stackoverflow on how to create custom cells and do sorting.